# How to keep the images staying on the screen size with html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I`m new to html and css and I will be taking a course in it next month. However right now I have a project to do by myself and I need to keep the products inside the screen size. How can I do this?

This is the html :

```
<div class="product-container">
    <li *ngFor="let product of products">
    <div class="product-title">

            <h2>
                {{product.title}}
            </h2>
            <div class="product-details">
                <img id="productImage" src={{product.imageUrl}}>
                <div>
                    <p>Description:</p>
                    <p>{{product.description}}</p>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <p>Location: <span>Mock Location</span></p>
                </div>
    
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </li>

</div>
```

This is the css I have so far :

```css
.product-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 90px;
}
.product-container li{
    list-style: none;
}
#productImage{
    height: 250px;
    width: 350px;
}
.special-details{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: large;
}
.product-title{
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is how bad it looks :
[image: screenshot]

Looking forward for any help and advice!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gap` css property is pushing them out of the `productContainer`.
If you need to preserve the width of the images use this:

```
 .product-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 90px;
    flex-wrap:wrap; // this is added
}
```